# Azure B2C.. Can not grant admin consent. Your organization does not have a subscription (or service principal) for the following API(s)

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I created a B2C Tenant and added a B2C Application ("nextware_code_generator") that is used to automate the creation of other B2C Applications for a several ASP.Net Web API apps.
I added the following API permissions to the nextware_code_generator as follows;

[image]

I created a .Net console app that runs as the above B2C ("nextware_code_generator") app which successfully creates a number of B2C Applications as per 4 existing ASP.Net Web API applications as follows;

[image]

The console app using the Graph API, programmatically creates the B2C applications and adds the scopes to each API's B2C app.
As well it adds all the necessary API permissions on each B2C application necessary to call other API service methods.

For example the nextware.productportal.coreservices.api B2C Application requires the following API permissions from two other Web API applications (4 scope items from nextware.productportal.sharedservices.api and (1 scope item from nextware.productportal.workspace.api)...

[image]

However when I attempt to manually grant consent on these new permissions I am not able to with the following error message...

[image]

Note: I am logged into Azure Portal using the Global Admin Account.

1. Why do I receive this error?
2. Is it possible to programmatically grant the above permissions?

Comment: Could you share how do you programmatically create the B2C applications using Graph API? I tried with portal, and it worked.

Comment: I think I may have resolved the issue.  I did not know that when creating AD Apps via MS Graph that you also need to create a Service Principal on the tenants you plan to use this app within.  It makes sense, just I didn't know.   I will post the solution once I have it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we learn through trial and error.

It turns out that it's not enough to create the AD App, I also had to create a service principal within the tenant of use per each AD (B2C) application as gleaned through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

My solution was to add this method below which I call after I create the AD(B2C) application.

```
  private static async Task AddServicePrincipal(GraphServiceClient graphClient, Microsoft.Graph.Application primaryApplication)
    {
        try
        {
            var servicePrincipal = new ServicePrincipal
            {
                AppId = primaryApplication.AppId
            };
            await graphClient.ServicePrincipals
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(servicePrincipal);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This has resolved my issues.  Hope that helps others with the same problem.